# Ajax function parameter passing to controller function in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on codeigniter. I am calling ajax function in a view page. Ajax function is calling controller method. Ajax function is containing 3 parameters which i want to pass to controller method but due to some reason i am not able to access parameter which is coming from ajax function.

My  ajax method call on drop-down change event (view page)

```
    $('#drp').change(function(e){  //dropdown change event
          var costcenter = $('#costcenter_id :selected').val(); //parameter 1
          var location1 = $('#location_id :selected').val(); //parameter 2
          var department = $('#department_id :selected').val(); //parameter 3
          $.ajax({
             cashe: false,
             type: 'POST',
             data:  {'costcenterid':costcenter,'locationid':location1,
                     'departmentid':department},
             url: 'http://local.desk.in/mycontroller/contollerfunction',
    success: function(data)
                {
                   alert("success");
                }
          });
        });
```

This is my controller method (method in controller)

```
public function controllerfunction($costcenterid,$locationid,$departmentid)
    {
    echo "costcenter= ". $costcenterid; 
    echo "location= ". $locationid; 
    echo "department= ". $departmentid;
    }
```

Getting error message :

```
Message: Missing argument 1 for assetcontroller::controllerfunction(), 
Message: Missing argument 2 for assetcontroller::controllerfunction(), 
Message: Missing argument 3 for assetcontroller::controllerfunction()
```

Why not able to send ajax parameter values to controller method?? Thanks in 
    advance

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

Your ajax should be like this  :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?=site_url('mycontroller/contollerfunction');?>",
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data:  {'costcenterid':costcenter, 'locationid': location1, 'departmentid':department},
    success: function(data)
    {
      alert("success");
    }
});
```

And your controller method `controllerfunction` should be like this :

Use CI inbuilt `$this->input->post()` to access the post items like this :

```
public function controllerfunction()
{
    $costcenterid = $this->input->post('costcenterid');
    $locationid = $this->input->post('locationid');
    $departmentid = $this->input->post('departmentid');
    $posts = array('costcenterid' => $costcenterid,
                   'locationid' =>  $locationid,
                   'departmentid' => $departmentid
             );
    print_r($posts);die;
}
```

Comment: if my answer helps you pls check it as green and do upvote me